# MYSQL: How could I iterate over table columns using a concatenated string as column name?

Tags: mysql, loops, string-concatenation

I am looking for a way to loop over columns in a MYSQL table using a concatenated string to index the column names within a loop. An example of the data in the table might look like this:

```
R1       R2     R3       R4     
0.68    0.08    0.04    4.24
0.15    1.17    3.06    0.57
1.59    0.48    1.39    1.00
1.59    0.77    1.13    0.22
0.90    0.23    0.73    0.52
```

The column names are simply the character "R" and a number (ultimately the number of columns will vary so the number could be up to 100). I would like to iterate over the columns to count the number of values in each column that exceed a threshold (I am using three thresholds: 3.0, 5.0 and 10.0). The result of calling the procedure should be something like the following:

```
str2    total   ThreeCount  FiveCount   TenCount
`R1`    8772    794            153        1

str2    total   ThreeCount  FiveCount   TenCount
`R2`    8772    382             42        0
```

etc.

I have been using the following code as a stored procedure to test the process (I am using 5 for the test and hence iterating over the first five columns of data values):

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE x  INT;
 DECLARE str1  VARCHAR(1);
 DECLARE str2  VARCHAR(5);
 DECLARE str3  VARCHAR(1);

 SET x = 1;
 SET str1 =  "R";
 SET str2 = "";
 SET str3 = "`";

 WHILE x  <= 5 DO
 SET  str2 = CONCAT(str3,str1,x,str3);
select str2,
    count(*) total,
    sum(case when str2 > 3.0 then 1 else 0 end) ThreeCount,
    sum(case when str2 > 5.0 then 1 else 0 end) FiveCount,
    sum(case when str2 > 10.0 then 1 else 0 end) TenCount
from test_dat;
SET  x = x + 1;
 END WHILE;

 END
```

However the procedure returns zero values (except for the total) unless I replace "str2" with the actual column names (e.g. replace str2 with `R1`, `R2` etc). However I would rather not use the actual column names.

What could I do to to have my concatenated string (str2) recognised as a column name? I have tried various combinations of concatenation such as:

```
SET  str2 = CONCAT(str1,x);
```

But have not got non-zero counts with any of these.

Thank you for any help you are able to offer.

Comment: This kind of problem cannot occur in an RDBMS. A database table is not a spreadsheet. Normalise your schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A normalised design might look something like this

```
id r val 
 1 1 0.68    
 2 1 0.15    
 3 1 1.59    
 4 1 1.59    
 5 1 0.90    

 6 2 0.08    
 7 2 1.17    
 8 2 0.48    
 9 2 0.77    
10 2 0.23 

11 3 0.04    
12 3 3.06    
13 3 1.39    
14 3 1.13    
15 3 0.73    

16 4 4.24
17 4 0.57
18 4 1.00
19 4 0.22
20 4 0.52
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion which I have implemented and it works fine. Much appreciated. I would still like to know if it is possible (and if so how) to use a concatenated string as a column name. Thank you so much for your help.